# Graph of a morphism of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes (here smooth, separated, of finite type over a field). Then the graph $\Gamma_f$ is defined as the image of the morphism $(id,f):X\to X\times Y$.

Claim: The structure sheaf of the graph is a coherent $\mathcal O_{X\times Y}$-module.

I tried to convince myself of this by considering the affine case first and got embarassingly confused:

So if $X=Spec\ (R)$ and $Y=Spec\ (S)$, then $X\times Y=Spec\ R\otimes S$. Let $f':S\to R$ be the corresponding ring homomorphism, then the graph should be just $\{s\otimes f'(s)\}$. And I guess I did something wrong here, because this is certainly no $S\otimes R$-module. The module generated by the set $\{s\otimes f'(s)\}$ on the other hand is the whole ring, because $f'(1)=1$.

It is easy to see that the graph is a closed subscheme, so it should be possible to write it as a quotient of $R\otimes S$.

Comment: In what sense is the image of a scheme morphism a sheaf?

Comment: A sorry, the structure sheaf of the subscheme... edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graph $\Gamma_f\subset X\times Y$ is a closed subscheme of $X\times Y$ and as such corresponds to an ideal  of the ring $R\otimes_k S$, as you very correctly stated.
That ideal is the kernel $I$ of the ring morphism $$ R\otimes_k S\to R: r\otimes s\mapsto rf'(s) \quad (\star) $$The structure sheaf $\mathscr O_{\Gamma_f} $ of the graph is then the $\mathscr O_{X\times_kY}$- module $\widetilde {\frac {R\otimes_k S}{I}}$ corresponding to the $R\otimes_k S $- module $\frac {R\otimes_k S}{I}$  and is thus coherent.
 [Because $R\otimes_k S$ is noetherian. Beware that the structure sheaf of a scheme, even an affine one, needn't be coherent in the absence of noetherianness]
Note that the first projection $X\times_kY\to X$ restricts to an isomorphism $\Gamma_f \stackrel {\cong}{\to} X$ corresponding to the inverse of the isomorphism $\frac {R\otimes_k S}{I} \stackrel {\cong}{\to}  R $ deduced from $(\star) $.

Answer (score 3):

The (pushforward of the structure sheaf of the) graph is $R$ regarded as an $S$-module via the homomorphism $f$ and regarded as an $R$-module in the obvious way.

Comment: Thanks. That was easy. I guess this is a sign for me to just go home.

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, the structure sheaf of the  graph corresponds to a $R\otimes_k S$-module (actually a quotient by an ideal), not an $S$-module, since the graph is a subscheme of $X\times_kY$, and not a subscheme of $Y$. I'll develop this comment into an answer. (It is true that the graph is isomorphic to $X$, and this is a bit confusing).

Comment: @Georges: but the $R$ and $S$-module structures above commute. This gives an $R \otimes_k S$-module structure, yes?

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, I'm not sure I understand your comment.  
 Subschemes of $X\times_kY$ are in bijective correspondence with ideals $I\subset R\otimes_kS$.   
Given such an $I$, could you please explain how you  find an $S$-module $M$ which will give back $I$ ?

Comment: @Georges: did you miss the "and regarded as an $R$-module" in my answer? I'm making no claim that an $S$-module structure is enough. And admittedly I'm identifying the pushforward of the structure sheaf of the graph rather than the graph itself. (Perhaps it's not true that you can recover a subscheme from the pushforward of its structure sheaf?)

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, I'm sure there are quite interesting developments  stemming from your point of view,  but I feel I have already exceeded the reasonable number of comments and will stop adding to them. Users now have two answers and I'm very afraid of  giving the impression that I'm trying to criticize yours in order to support  mine .